# Swap Concurrent Function

Tags: go, concurrency, routines

I am trying to figure out how to make concurrent the forward Swap function in Go for learning concepts purpose:

```
package main 

import "fmt"

func Swap(a, b int) (int, int) {
  return b, a
}

func main() {
  for i := 0; i <10; i++ {
   fmt.Println(Swap(i+1, i))
  }
}
```

So far I have came up with this solution:

```
package main

import "fmt"


// Only Send Channel
func Swap(a, b chan<- int) {
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            a <- i + 1
            b <- i
        }
    }()
}

func main() {

    a := make(chan int)
    b := make(chan int)

    Swap(a, b)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("chan a received: %d | chan b received: %d\n", <-a, <-b)
    }
}
```

It seems to work but I cannot be sure about it.
How can I measure this and does anyone knows how to really make a simple Swap function concurrent in Go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for the question but I figured out how to solve this.
It took days for me to be able to do this and on the day I posted at this forum some hours later I discovered how to solve it.
I am going to post the code and the walkthrough this was given to me in a Senior Golang Job Interview and I could not answer, I hope this can help someone.

```
// Pass as a parameter a int slice of type channel
// Send the swapped information throw the channel
func Swap(a, b int, ch chan []int) {
    ch <- []int{b, a}
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan []int)

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        // Call Worker with the created channel
        go Swap(i+1, i, ch)
    }

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        // Receive Channel Value
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }
}
```

I really appreciate any comments, improvements and conceptual references on this.